# How to watch to $scope variable changed from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to run some code when my `$scope.count` is changed from controller it self. What I tried using `$scope.$watch` function but its not detected only. [fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/19d5eLoq/)
HTML:

```
See your console
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
   <p>
    Count : {{greeting}}
   </p>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
function MyCtrl2($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;

  $scope.$watch("count", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.greeting = $scope.count;
  });

 window.setInterval(function(){ 
    $scope.count++; 
    console.log('$scope.count : '+$scope.count);
 }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of would be to broadcast the change and then listen for such a broadcast. This could be a comparatively less expensive option.

Eg: Where you would be changing the count, after making the change do a broadcast:

//Count modified in code

`$rootScope.$broadcast('count-changed');`

Then you could listen to it where requried:

```
$scope.$on('count-changed', function(event, args) {

    // do what you want to do
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use angular's `$interval` service instead of `setInterval` for angular to be able to keep track of the variables that get changed.

Try:

```
function MyCtrl2($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.count = 0;

  $scope.$watch("count", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.greeting = $scope.count;
  });

 $interval(function(){ 
    $scope.count++; 
    console.log('$scope.count : '+$scope.count);
 }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: `$interval` is a not point @zadaz what if I changing count in some other directive or based on some other condition

Comment: `$interval` is just wrapper around `setInterval` with `$scope.$apply` call at the end. You can receive `digest is already in progress` error, when you call `$scope.$apply` manually from angular wrapped functions like `$timeout`/`$interval`/`$http.get`/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$scope.$apply()` as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b0q19bxn/2/)

You are using `setInterval` that doesnt calls digest cycle, alternatively you can use angular's $interval()

```
function MyCtrl2($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;

  $scope.$watch("count", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.greeting = $scope.count;
  });

  window.setInterval(function(){ 
            $scope.count++; 
        console.log('$scope.count : '+$scope.count);
       $scope.$apply()
  }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: wen i did that I am getting this error Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Answer (score 1):

Use `$scope.$apply`

```
  window.setInterval(function(){ 
            $scope.count++; 
        console.log('$scope.count1 : '+$scope.count);
        $scope.greeting = $scope.count;
        $scope.$apply();
  }, 1000);
```